# Ensuring QProcess termination on termination of its parent QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt

I am writing a code within Qt where I am using multiple threads (Qthreads) to launch command-line processes in a manner shown in the code snippet below:

```
void test_streamer_thread::run()
{
    QProcess    start_process;
    ...

    ret_status = start_process.execute("some_cmd.exe",some_args);
    start_process.close();
}
```

Once launched, the process goes on infinitely (shows up as a separate process in the windows task manager). However, when the application terminates, the process still continues to exist. How do I ensure that this process terminates on termination of the application launching it.

Answer (score 3):

Using separate threads to launch processes is entirely unnecessary.

The simplest way to ensure that child processes are terminated when the application terminates would be

```
QProcess * p = new QProcess(....);
connect(qApp, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), process, SLOT(terminate()));
```

See below for a complete example.

There's this misunderstadning that is spreading like a disease that threads are the solution to everyone's problems. My observation is that in 9 out of 10 posts with the `Qt` tag, the use of threads is unnecessary and is a result of not understanding the problem.

My rule is: if you think you need to use threads, try explaining it, if only in your mind, to convince your coworker. After doing this, check that all the facts you cited to back your argument are in fact true. In many cases, they aren't.

The example code below does not catch Unix signals, so -- as you'll notice on Linux and OS X -- it'll only terminate the direct descendant process, not any subsequent ones that might have been launched from it. You would [need to handle Unix signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/unix-signals.html) to fix that.

```
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QProcess>

class Launcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int n;
    QProcess * process;
signals:
    void setDisabled(bool);
public slots:
    void launch() {
        QStringList args;
        args << QString::number(n);
        process = new QProcess(this);
        process->start(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath(), args);
        connect(qApp, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), process, SLOT(terminate()));
        emit setDisabled(true);
    }
public:
    Launcher(int no) : n(no), process(0) {}
    ~Launcher() {
        if (process) {
            process->terminate();
            process->waitForFinished();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    int n = 0;
    if (argc > 1) n = QByteArray(argv[1]).toInt();
    Launcher launcher(n+1);
    QPushButton spawn(QString("Spawn #%1").arg(n));
    launcher.connect(&spawn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(launch()));
    spawn.connect(&launcher, SIGNAL(setDisabled(bool)), SLOT(setDisabled(bool)));
    spawn.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are forking a separate process, not creating threads.

If its a separate process, then you will need some sort of communication between the parent and child process (maybe a pipe or a signal) to communicate that it should exit.

If it were threads, upon killing the process, all threads would die with it. Additionally, you wouldnt see the threads as separate processes in the windows task manager (not sure how they would appear, but they wouldnt appear as threads).